# Parent key of type encoded string?

Tags: google-app-engine

How do we create a parent key which is an encoded string? Example:

```
class Parent {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
    private String mEncKey;
}

class Child {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
    private String mEncKey;

    // In the doc examples, they have Key as the type here.
    @Persistent
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.parent-pk", value="true")
    private String mParentEncKey;
}
```

yeah I'm not sure how to make mParentEncKey an encoded string type, because the 'key' label is already being used? I would need something like?:

```
key="gae.parent-pk.encoded-pk"
```

not sure - is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for this, you can now map owned relations in a portable manner, check out [blog](http://blog.wp.weightpoint.se/2012/03/01/portable-owned-jdo-relations-appengine/).

Answer (score 0):

[This discussion](https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/43e38d0bc8a41bbd/0f0f86693330c1b2) says to just use `gae.parent-pk` - GAE will automatically use an encoded string value for a parent key field in Child.

https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/43e38d0bc8a41bbd/0f0f86693330c1b2